# python - returning top three artists for like users - data type error

Tags: python, pandas, collaborative-filtering

My code intends to generate three artist recommendations for a random user. This is a user-based collaberative filtering model, but I'm hitting an error which reads `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not Series` which points to the line where I assign `rating_c`.

I checked data types and cannot detect which part in that variable is registering as a Series. Does anyone see what could be the Series?

Below is the df head:

```
userArtist.head()

    users   artist             gender      plays    age
0   a       aesop rock         m           72       28.0
1   b       air                m           178      28.0
2   c       amon tobin         m           106      28.0
3   d       animal collective  m           203      28.0
4   e       annie              m           75       28.0
```

Code:

```
music_mat = userArtist.pivot_table(index='artist', columns='users', values='plays').fillna(0).apply(np.sign)
# user-item collaberative filtering of random user 
random_user = np.random.choice(userArtist.users)
# Check df for values of random user
random_user_rating = music_mat[random_user]
# Pairwise correlation of top five similar users 
user_corr = music_mat.corrwith(random_user_rating)[:5]

rating_c = userArtist[(userArtist.artist.isnull().values) & (userArtist.users != random_user)]
rating_c['similarity'] = rating_c['users'].map(user_corr.get)
rating_c['sim_rating'] = rating_c.similarity * rating_c.plays

recommendation = rating_c.groupby('artist').apply(lambda s: s.sim_rating.sum() / s.similarity.sum())
recommendation
```

Comment: Could you check if `random_user` is a series? I think it's a string here.

Comment: @RyanTam it's a string

Comment: `random_user[userArtist.artist].isnull()` is the issue here then.

Comment: @RyanTam what's the equivalent of `isnull()` for checking empty string value?

Comment: `len("")==0` <- this checks for empty string (or just `len("")` really), but the issue here is `random_user[userArtist.artist]` fails, you can't select substring through a pd.Series. (Basically you are doing something like `"i_am_a_string"[pd.Series([1,2])]`, which doesn't work)

Comment: @RyanTam I revised my code above, which now dodges any errors, but the output is showing 0 returned artist recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake in line:

```py
rating_c = userArtist[random_user[userArtist.artist].isnull().values & (userArtist.users != random_user)]
```

*random_user*, as you've defined, is a string, and you are indexing it with a Series

```
random_user[userArtist.artist]
```

Comment: do i need to rervse their order when slicing?

Comment: Well, your currently code, as seen at this moment, appears to be running. 

I copied it and ran with the data you've exposed. Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/abevieiramota/54d69f5d0fd3aa14e9f1b26b088cf971